# React Lifecycles managing intervals with changing values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval, use-effect, usecallback

In one of my components I have a `useEffect` setup where an interval is set to fetch a function.

It's basically set up as follows:

```javascript
...

const token = useToken() // custom hook that updates whenever access_token updates

const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
  callAPI(token)
}, [token])

useEffect(() => {
  if (!token) return

  fetchData()

  const interval = setInterval(fetchData, 60000)

  return () => {
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
}, [token]}

...
```

It is supposed `fetchData` every 60 seconds which it does.

What it also needs to do (which it doesn't) is whenever the `token` is updated, it should account for that.

What I've currently done to try solve that is clear the interval when the token changes and start the process over. But I think I've handled that incorrectly in my attempts above.

Any idea on how to accomplish this correctly?

Comment: when token changes do you also what to call `fetchData` or just make sure that it uses the updated token?

Comment: Just want to make sure it uses the updated token, I'm not too phased if it does recall `fetchData` though. But first prize would be to stick to 60 second intervals and just if the token updates, use the new one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only thing missing is `fetchData` should be added to the dependency array to make sure that the `useEffect` uses the updated callback

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) return

    fetchData()

    const interval = setInterval(fetchData, 60000)

    return () => {
        clearInterval(interval)
    }
}, [token, fetchData])
```

but you can also move the `fetchData`(this time `fetchData` doesn't have to be memorized with `useCallback`) function inside the `useEffect`, that way you can only have token as a dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
        if(!token) return;

        callAPI(token)
    };

    fetchData();
    const interval = setInterval(fetchData, 60000)

    return () => {
        clearInterval(interval)
    }
}, [token])
```

Edit:
You can remove token form the `useEffect` this way:

```
const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
    if(!token) return; // moved the token check here
    
    callAPI(token)
  }, [token])
  
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    const interval = setInterval(fetchData, 60000)

    return () => {
        clearInterval(interval)
    }
}, [fetchData])
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot and let you know if that solves it :)

Comment: I don't understand why `fetchData` needs to be added to the dependency array of that `useEffect` though.

Comment: It's confusing because `fetchData` is also using token as a dependency. When token changes fetchData gets updated and useEffect will also trigger but the function that is known to the useEffect may not be the latest fetchData.

Comment: Ok interesting, yeah I've been a bit confused by this because I thought `useEffect` dependency array values work a little differently to useCallback since they're what trigger a re-rerun. Wouldn't this theoretically mean I don't need to keep `token` in the `useEffect` dependency array anymore then since it's already covered in `fetchData`?

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle Yes, you can do that. But you have to make sure that the token is not used anywhere else in the `useEffect` other than inside `fetchData`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, fantastic that makes sense :) Thanks, just busy testing everything and making sure it works!